# Comparing two lists are loaded from files in python

Tags: python

I got 2 files

file1.txt

```
2C:E4:12:B2:EC:4B;20120731_10:06:36;20151005_13:44:51;195.116.227.97
2C:E4:12:B2:26:E0;20120902_21:48:58;20151005_17:01:10;195.116.227.97
E8:BE:81:87:76:10;20131006_20:23:44;20151004_23:56:37;195.116.227.97
.....
```

file2.txt

```
C8:91:F9:98:13:4B;2015/09/24 13:30:53
E8:BE:81:87:76:10;2015/09/24 13:30:41
7C:03:D8:3A:BF:14;2015/09/24 13:32:35
18:1E:78:E9:6E:C6;2015/09/24 13:33:46
.....
```

If first column (mac) in file1 is in file2 I want to get the all line from file2 and print, so output will be in this case:

```
E8:BE:81:87:76:10;2015/09/24 13:30:41
```

I don't know how to compare list in python

my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

list = {}
list1 = {}
file = open('file.txt','r')
for line in file:
        mac,first,last,ip = line.split(';')
        list = mac


file1 = open('file1.txt','r')
for line in file1:
        mac,data = line.split(';')
        list1 = mac,data
# ........
```

and what's now?

Comment: Why are you initialising the names to empty *dictionaries*?! Also, don't use the name `list` for your own list. If your question is *"how can I compare two lists?"*, then... `list1 == list2`?

Answer (score 1):

Store all MAC addresses from file 1 in a *set* first; now you can test the second file against that set:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as inf:
    mac_addresses = {line.partition(';')[0] for line in inf}

with open('file2.txt', 'r') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        if line.partition(';')[0] in mac_addresses:
            print(line.strip())
```

I used a set comprehension to build the `mac_addresses` set; each line from the file is split (using `str.partition()`, slightly faster for splitting on just the first delimiter) and only the first element is retained.

The `str.strip()` call is needed to remove the trailing newline each line has. Alternatively, if on Python 3, use `print(line, end='')`.